# Standard distribution formulae trick

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am trying to understand the following question.

The height of adult males is normally distributed with a mean of 172cm and standard deviation of 8cm. If 99% of adult males exceed a certain height, what is this height?
The Answer given 153.4cm.
Here is what i understood so far:

Since the question says 99% of them exceeded a certain height, i am definetly sure the height is at the left hand side of the bell curve. Everything right to the height is 99%, and everything to the left is 1%. I need to use the formula
Z = x-mean / sigma

The z score at 99% is 2.3, so 2.3 = x-172 / 8

However, I am not able to arrive at the correct answer, but if i swap x and mean from the equation, i get the answer. Why?

Comment: Always keep in mind *which* table you are looking up z-score values and results from.  Some show the area under the curve *to the left* of the value, some show the area under the curve *to the right* of the value, and others still show the area under the curve *between* the value and its additive inverse.  Any of these tables has the ability to give all of the information of the other tables.  In your problem, you were asked to find the z value such that 1% is to the left.  If your table was for *to the left*, you will find that corresponds to the value of $-2.3$, not positive $2.3$.

Answer (score 3):

You might have forgotten to take the negative value. $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}=-2.33$, so $x=153.36\approx153.4$.

Comment: You are right. We can  use x-mean / sigma  = -2.33( by looking up the table value of 0.01 which is 1%). But i can also use mean-x / sigma = 2.33.  What is the logic behind swapping x and mean ?

Comment: @user3227275 We take $x-\mu$ because its $+$-ve (or $-$-ve) difference means that the $x$ is right-hand-side (or left-hand-side). This aligns with the number line by convention: the bigger, the righter; or the smaller, the lefter.